# How to Fix Entry Point Not Found while installing libraries in conda environment

Tags: anaconda, environment-variables, conda, entry-point

I'm working on Anaconda by making multiple environments in it. I have made an environment `camelot` and now I want to install different libraries in this environment. So for example to install `pandas` in this environment,
I'm writing:

```
conda install pandas
```

or

```
conda install -c conda-forge camelot-py
```

Then it gives me this error:

```
python.exe-Entry Point Not Found
   The procedure entry point OPENSSL_sk_new_reserve could not be 
   located in the dynamic link library.
   C:\Users\abc\Anaconda3\Library\bin\libssl11_-x64.dll
```

First I thought it may be because of the environment variable, thus I set an environment variable for Python, but this did not resolve the issue.

Comment: The following solved the issue for me
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9003#issuecomment-539348297

Comment: @UsmanGhaniMughal You've received a number of working suggestions. Please consider marking one of the as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 57):

as it is suggested in [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9003#issuecomment-516499958) I could solve this problem by copying `libssl-1_1-x64 dlls` in `Anaconda/DLLS` to `Anaconda/Library/bin` (probably replacing it)

Comment: Just copying DLLs is not advisable. See my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59884311/625350)

Answer (score 17):

I got the same issue while updating Anaconda navigator, and got it over by replacing the file **libssl-1_1-x64.dll** in *Anaconda3/Library/bin* with the one from *Anaconda3/DLLs*.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem for me.

Comment: This fixed the problem, but it broke openssl for me. I had to do `conda clear --all` and `conda install openssl --force-reinstall` to fix that, as suggested by @titusjan.

Comment: Not `conda clean --all`?

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned by an Anaconda maintainer [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9003#issuecomment-553529174) ...

> moving libssl dlls around like that is really not advisable. Those
>   DLLs are duplicated because you have something fishy going on in your
>   packages. There should not be any openssl DLLs in the DLLs folder.
>   They should be in Library/bin

By looking at the JSON files in the `conda-meta` directory I found out that `DLLs\libssl-1_1-x64.dll` was installed by the `python 3.7.0` package, and `Library\bin\libssl-1_1-x64.dll` was installed by the `openssl` package. After further investigation I found out that Python 3.7.0 does **not** install OpenSSL as a separate package, but Python 3.7.1 (and later) **does**.

Typically upgrading Python goes as expected, but if you somehow end up with both `python 3.7.0` and `openssl` packages installed simultaneously there will be two `libssl-1_1-x64.dll` files and your Anaconda distribution will be broken. (You can easily verify this with the `conda list` command.)

I think the best way to fix it is therefore:

1. Rename `Library\bin\libssl-1_1-x64.dll` to `Library\bin\libssl-1_1-x64.dll.org` (your are going to need it later.)
2. Copy `DLLs\libssl-1_1-x64.dll` to `Library\bin\libssl-1_1-x64.dll`
3. Update Python to version 3.7.1 or higher, for instance with `conda update python`. This will remove the `DLLs\libssl-1_1-x64.dll` file.
4. Delete the current `Library\bin\libssl-1_1-x64.dll` file.
5. Rename `Library\bin\libssl-1_1-x64.dll.org` back to `Library\bin\libssl-1_1-x64.dll`. This is necessary because I got HTTP errors in the next step otherwise.
6. Reinstall OpenSSL with `conda install openssl --force-reinstall` to ensure it's up to date again.

Answer (score 9):

I had the exact same issue, and it also just started today. Kind of destroyed my entire work day, tbh...

I accidentally did a `conda install ...` in my base environment, and it updated conda and a handful of other modules. (Conda went from 4.5.12 to 4.7.10, in my case.) Anyway, after I rolled it back, things are working as expected again.

If this is what's causing your issue, here's a fix.

1. `conda list --revisions`
2. `conda install --revision 1` (In my case "rev 1" was my most recent, stable base environment.)

(More details about this: https://sriramjaju.github.io/2018-05-30-2-minute-recipe-how-to-rollback-your-conda-environment/)

Now I'm worried that I've inadvertently configured something in a way that isn't compatible with the newest version of conda.

*Edit: Don't follow this last suggestion if you're doing anything other than playing around in a conda environment to test-drive modules. See [this](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment#:%7E:text=In%20summary%2C%20when%20combining%20conda,to%20install%20any%20remaining%20software.) and [this](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#using-pip-in-an-environment).*

Lastly, if you really need to install modules and do some work ASAP, `pip install [module name]` was still working for me before I thought to do the reversion thing.

Comment: Yes!  same thing for me I just update conda in my base env, and yes pip is woking fine but cannot install any thing using conda. Do you have any idea about how to use, camelot packge?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience with camelot. Were you able to revert to an earlier revision and get conda working again, though?

Comment: I have uninstall anaconda fully and then reinstall it now it's working I don't know how but it's working I think it's because of conda update I did before in my base env

Comment: I'm glad to hear it! Good luck with camelot. :)

Comment: Thank you man! This solution works in my case as well !. I am not sure why the updated conda version has this problem!

Comment: Your recommendation is not good for people using conda environments. The OP's question is about resolving issues in the conda environment. Using pip within conda environments can corrupt the conda environment, because pip does not do environment consistency checking for conda environments. It puts packages into the environment that conda is subsequently not aware of. For more information see conda man pages: 
 https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#using-pip-in-an-environment

Comment: @RichLysakowskiPhD Good callout. I've edited my response. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

My problem was same. I just uninstalled anaconda, and install it again. And the problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

I was receiving the same following error while updating spyder and conda package.

```
python.exe-Entry Point Not Found
   The procedure entry point OPENSSL_sk_new_reserve could not be 
   located in the dynamic link library.
   C:\Users\abc\Anaconda3\Library\bin\libssl11_-x64.dll
```

solution:

- I did replace `libssl-1_1-x64 dlls` from `Anaconda/DLLs` to
  `Anaconda/Library/bins` as suggested [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9003#issuecomment-539348297).
- ***Before opening Anaconda Navigator desktop app***, I updated conda in Anaconda Prompt using `conda update conda`. conda successfully updated.
- Then I have updated spyder using `conda update spyder` command in
  Anaconda Prompt. spyder updated and running successfully.

Comment: This appears to have solved an issue I've been suffering for too long. I haven't been able to use conda install for months due to dll errors. I just tried after doing what is suggested in @Pathik's answer here and it worked! This is so helpful to me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For those still having similar issues with `libssl11_-x64.dll` or other `.dll` files:

***Use `pip install` instead if you can!***

---

I had the same issue today with `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll` when trying to install plotly using

```
conda install -c plotly plotly
```

This prompts a downgrade for anaconda, and  in turn raises the error:

> OPENSSL_sk_new_reserve [...] libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll

Instead, using for example

```
pip install plotly==4.1.0
```

works like a charm!

Comment: Your answer is off-topic and a bad recommendation for people using conda environments.  The OP's question is about resolving issues in the conda environment.  Using pip within conda environments can corrupt the conda environment, because pip does not do environment consistency checking for conda environments.  It puts packages into the environment that conda is subsequently not aware of.  For more information see conda manual https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#using-pip-in-an-environment

Comment: @RichLysakowskiPhD Thank you for the feedback! Please provide a better solution if you have one. And if you should feel so inclined, feel free to flag my answer as either `Not an answer`, or `In need of moderator intervention`. In the latter case, don't forget to leave a specific and detailed explanation.