# Conda Entry Point Errors Related to `conda-content-trust` and `conda-libmamba-solver` on Windows 10

Tags: openssl, anaconda, conda, anaconda3, libssl

I encounter entry point errors when I execute Conda commands like `conda env list` or `conda update [...]` on a 64-bit Windows 10 Pro using Anaconda3 (`conda 23.7.4` and `Python 3.11.8` for the base environment).

The error messages are as follows:

```
Error while loading conda entry point: conda-content-trust (No module named 'cryptography.exceptions')
Error while loading conda entry point: conda-libmamba-solver (module 'libmambapy' has no attribute 'Context')
WARNING conda.plugins.manager:load_entrypoints(114): Error while loading conda entry point: conda-content-trust (No module named 'cryptography.exceptions')
WARNING conda.plugins.manager:load_entrypoints(114): Error while loading conda entry point: conda-libmamba-solver (module 'libmambapy' has no attribute 'Context')
```

I have the following Anaconda components:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_anaconda_depends         2023.09             py311_mkl_1
anaconda-anon-usage       0.4.2           py311hfc23b7f_0
anaconda-catalogs         0.2.0           py311haa95532_0
anaconda-client           1.12.1          py311haa95532_0
anaconda-navigator        2.5.0           py311haa95532_0
anaconda-project          0.11.1          py311haa95532_0
```

I came across a [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57254007/how-to-fix-entry-point-not-found-while-installing-libraries-in-conda-environment) to copy the `DLLs\libssl-1_1-x64.dll` file to `Library\bin\libssl-1_1-x64.dll`. However, I could not find `libssl-1_1-x64.dll` in my `anaconda3\DLLs` directory.

Instead, I found `libssl-3-x64.dll` and `libcrypto-3-x64.dll` files under `Library\bin`, which appear to be newer versions.

I cannot apply the suggested fix since I can't find `libssl-1_1-x64.dll`. How can I resolve these errors? Are there any steps to address this with the newer version of the files I have?

(Update) I have the following `conda` packages:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_anaconda_depends         2023.09             py311_mkl_1
abseil-cpp                20211102.0           hd77b12b_0
aiofiles                  22.1.0          py311haa95532_0
aioitertools              0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
aiosignal                 1.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
aiosqlite                 0.18.0          py311haa95532_0
alabaster                 0.7.12             pyhd3eb1b0_0
anaconda-anon-usage       0.4.2           py311hfc23b7f_0
anaconda-catalogs         0.2.0           py311haa95532_0
anaconda-client           1.12.1          py311haa95532_0
anaconda-navigator        2.5.0           py311haa95532_0
anaconda-project          0.11.1          py311haa95532_0
annotated-types           0.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
anyio                     3.5.0           py311haa95532_0
aom                       3.6.0                hd77b12b_0
appdirs                   1.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
argon2-cffi               21.3.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0          py311h2bbff1b_0
arrow                     1.2.3           py311haa95532_1
astroid                   2.14.2          py311haa95532_0
asttokens                 2.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
atomicwrites              1.4.0                      py_0
attrs                     23.2.0             pyh71513ae_0    conda-forge
automat                   20.2.0                     py_0
autopep8                  2.0.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
babel                     2.11.0          py311haa95532_0
backports                 1.1                pyhd3eb1b0_0
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
backports.tempfile        1.0                pyhd3eb1b0_1
backports.weakref         1.0.post1                  py_1
bcrypt                    3.2.0           py311h2bbff1b_1
beautifulsoup4            4.12.2          py311haa95532_0
binaryornot               0.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_1
black                     24.2.0          py311h1ea47a8_0    conda-forge
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    4.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
blosc                     1.21.3               h6c2663c_0
boltons                   23.0.0          py311haa95532_0
brotli                    1.0.9                h2bbff1b_7
brotli-bin                1.0.9                h2bbff1b_7
brotli-python             1.0.9           py311h12c1d0e_8    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                hcfcfb64_5    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.19.1               h2bbff1b_0
ca-certificates           2024.2.2             h56e8100_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2024.2.2           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cfitsio                   3.470                h2bbff1b_7
chardet                   4.0.0           py311haa95532_1003
charls                    2.2.0                h6c2663c_0
charset-normalizer        2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
click                     8.1.7           win_pyh7428d3b_0    conda-forge
cloudpickle               2.2.1           py311haa95532_0
clyent                    1.2.2           py311haa95532_1
colorama                  0.4.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
colorcet                  3.0.1           py311haa95532_0
comm                      0.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
conda                     23.7.4          py311haa95532_0
conda-build               3.26.1          py311haa95532_0
conda-content-trust       0.2.0           py311haa95532_0
conda-libmamba-solver     23.7.0          py311haa95532_0
conda-pack                0.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda-package-handling    2.2.0           py311haa95532_0
conda-package-streaming   0.9.0           py311haa95532_0
conda-repo-cli            1.0.75          py311haa95532_0
conda-token               0.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1
console_shortcut          0.1.1                         4
cookiecutter              2.5.0              pyhca7485f_0    conda-forge
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
daal4py                   2023.1.1        py311h30df693_0
datasets                  2.12.0          py311haa95532_0
dav1d                     1.2.1                h2bbff1b_0
debugpy                   1.8.1           py311h12c1d0e_0    conda-forge
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
diff-match-patch          20200713           pyhd3eb1b0_0
dill                      0.3.6           py311haa95532_0
distro                    1.8.0           py311haa95532_0
docstring-to-markdown     0.11            py311haa95532_0
docutils                  0.18.1          py311haa95532_3
entrypoints               0.4                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
et_xmlfile                1.1.0           py311haa95532_0
exceptiongroup            1.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
executing                 2.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ffmpy                     0.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
flake8                    7.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
fmt                       9.1.0                h6d14046_0
fonttools                 4.25.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
freetype                  2.12.1               ha860e81_0
future                    0.18.3          py311haa95532_0
gensim                    4.3.0           py311heda8569_0
giflib                    5.2.1                h8cc25b3_3
glob2                     0.7                pyhd3eb1b0_0
grpc-cpp                  1.48.2               hfe90ff0_1
h11                       0.14.0          py311haa95532_0
h5py                      3.9.0           py311h4e0e482_0
hdf5                      1.12.1               h51c971a_3
heapdict                  1.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
httpcore                  1.0.2           py311haa95532_0
httpx                     0.26.0          py311haa95532_0
hyperlink                 21.0.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
icc_rt                    2022.1.0             h6049295_2
icu                       73.2                 h63175ca_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.4             py311haa95532_0
imagecodecs               2023.1.23       py311he6ff3c7_0
imagesize                 1.4.1           py311haa95532_0
importlib-metadata        7.0.1              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        7.0.1                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib_resources       6.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
incremental               21.3.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
inflection                0.5.1           py311haa95532_0
iniconfig                 1.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
intake                    0.6.8           py311haa95532_0
intervaltree              3.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
ipykernel                 6.29.2             pyha63f2e9_0    conda-forge
ipython                   8.21.0             pyh7428d3b_0    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
ipywidgets                8.0.4           py311haa95532_0
isort                     5.9.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
itemadapter               0.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
itemloaders               1.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_1
itsdangerous              2.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jaraco.classes            3.2.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jedi                      0.19.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jellyfish                 1.0.1           py311h36a85e1_0
jinja2                    3.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
joblib                    1.2.0           py311haa95532_0
jpeg                      9e                   h2bbff1b_1
jq                        1.6                  haa95532_1
json5                     0.9.6              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jsonpatch                 1.32               pyhd3eb1b0_0
jsonpointer               2.1                pyhd3eb1b0_0
jsonschema                4.21.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jsonschema-specifications 2023.12.1          pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            7.4.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_console           6.6.3           py311haa95532_0
jupyter_core              5.7.1           py311h1ea47a8_0    conda-forge
jupyter_server            1.23.4          py311haa95532_0
jupyter_server_fileid     0.9.0           py311haa95532_0
jupyter_server_ydoc       0.8.0           py311haa95532_1
jupyter_ydoc              0.2.4           py311haa95532_0
jupyterlab_pygments       0.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
kaleido-core              0.2.1                h2bbff1b_0
keyring                   23.13.1         py311haa95532_0
kiwisolver                1.4.4           py311hd77b12b_0
krb5                      1.20.1               h5b6d351_0
lazy-object-proxy         1.6.0           py311h2bbff1b_0
lcms2                     2.12                 h83e58a3_0
lerc                      3.0                  hd77b12b_0
libaec                    1.0.4                h33f27b4_1
libarchive                3.6.2                hb62f4d4_2
libavif                   0.11.1               h2bbff1b_0
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                h2bbff1b_7
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                h2bbff1b_7
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                h2bbff1b_7
libclang                  14.0.6          default_hb5a9fac_1
libclang13                14.0.6          default_h8e68704_1
libevent                  2.1.12               h56d1f94_1
libexpat                  2.5.0                h63175ca_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.4                hd77b12b_0
libiconv                  1.16                 h2bbff1b_2
liblief                   0.12.3               hd77b12b_0
libpng                    1.6.39               h8cc25b3_0
libpq                     12.17                h906ac69_0
libprotobuf               3.20.3               h23ce68f_0
libsodium                 1.0.18               h8d14728_1    conda-forge
libsolv                   0.7.24               h23ce68f_0
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h6c2663c_0
libsqlite                 3.45.1               hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.10.0               he2ea4bf_2
libthrift                 0.15.0               h4364b78_2
libtiff                   4.5.1                hd77b12b_0
libwebp-base              1.3.2                h2bbff1b_0
libxml2                   2.10.4               h0ad7f3c_1
libxslt                   1.1.37               h2bbff1b_1
libzlib                   1.2.13               hcfcfb64_5    conda-forge
libzopfli                 1.0.3                ha925a31_0
linkify-it-py             2.0.0           py311haa95532_0
locket                    1.0.0           py311haa95532_0
lxml                      4.9.3           py311h09808a7_0
lz4                       4.3.2           py311h2bbff1b_0
lz4-c                     1.9.4                h2bbff1b_0
lzo                       2.10                 he774522_2
m2-msys2-runtime          2.5.0.17080.65c939c               3
m2-patch                  2.7.5                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
markdown                  3.4.1           py311haa95532_0
markdown-it-py            2.2.0           py311haa95532_1
markupsafe                2.1.5           py311ha68e1ae_0    conda-forge
mathjax                   2.7.5                haa95532_0
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mccabe                    0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
mdit-py-plugins           0.3.0           py311haa95532_0
mdurl                     0.1.0           py311haa95532_0
menuinst                  1.4.19          py311h59b6b97_1
mistune                   3.0.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mkl-service               2.4.0           py311h2bbff1b_1
mkl_fft                   1.3.8           py311h2bbff1b_0
mkl_random                1.2.4           py311h59b6b97_0
mpmath                    1.3.0           py311haa95532_0
msgpack-python            1.0.3           py311h59b6b97_0
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
multipledispatch          0.6.0           py311haa95532_0
multiprocess              0.70.14         py311haa95532_0
munkres                   1.1.4                      py_0
mypy_extensions           1.0.0           py311haa95532_0
navigator-updater         0.4.0           py311haa95532_1
nbclient                  0.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbconvert                 7.16.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbconvert-core            7.16.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbconvert-pandoc          7.16.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbformat                  5.9.2           py311haa95532_0
nest-asyncio              1.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
networkx                  3.1             py311haa95532_0
nltk                      3.8.1           py311haa95532_0
notebook                  6.5.4           py311haa95532_1
numpydoc                  1.5.0           py311haa95532_0
openai                    1.13.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
opencv-python             4.9.0.80                 pypi_0    pypi
openjpeg                  2.4.0                h4fc8c34_0
openpyxl                  3.0.10          py311h2bbff1b_0
openssl                   3.2.1                hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
orc                       1.7.4                h623e30f_1
packaging                 23.2               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pandoc                    3.1.12.1             h57928b3_0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
paramiko                  2.8.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pathlib                   1.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_1
pathspec                  0.10.3          py311haa95532_0
patsy                     0.5.3           py311haa95532_0
pcre2                     10.42                h0ff8eda_0
pep8                      1.7.1           py311haa95532_1
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pip                       24.0               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pkce                      1.0.3           py311haa95532_0
pkginfo                   1.9.6           py311haa95532_0
pkgutil-resolve-name      1.3.10             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
platformdirs              4.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
plotly                    5.9.0           py311haa95532_0
pluggy                    1.0.0           py311haa95532_1
ply                       3.11            py311haa95532_0
powershell_shortcut       0.0.1                         3
prometheus_client         0.14.1          py311haa95532_0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.42             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
protego                   0.1.16                     py_0
psutil                    5.9.8           py311ha68e1ae_0    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
py-lief                   0.12.3          py311hd77b12b_0
pyasn1                    0.4.8              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                      py_0
pybind11-abi              4                    hd3eb1b0_1
pycodestyle               2.11.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyct                      0.5.0           py311haa95532_0
pycurl                    7.45.2          py311he2ea4bf_1
pydantic                  2.6.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pydantic-core             2.16.2          py311hc37eb10_1    conda-forge
pydispatcher              2.0.5           py311haa95532_2
pydocstyle                6.3.0           py311haa95532_0
pyerfa                    2.0.0           py311h2bbff1b_0
pyflakes                  3.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pygments                  2.17.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyjwt                     2.4.0           py311haa95532_0
pylint                    2.16.2          py311haa95532_0
pylint-venv               3.0.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyls-spyder               0.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pynacl                    1.5.0           py311h8cc25b3_0
pyparsing                 3.0.9           py311haa95532_0
pyqt                      5.15.10         py311hd77b12b_0
pyqt5-sip                 12.13.0         py311h2bbff1b_0
pyqtwebengine             5.15.10         py311hd77b12b_0
pysocks                   1.7.1           py311haa95532_0
pytest                    7.4.0           py311haa95532_0
python                    3.11.8          h2628c8c_0_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-dotenv             0.21.0          py311haa95532_0
python-fastjsonschema     2.16.2          py311haa95532_0
python-json-logger        2.0.7           py311haa95532_0
python-kaleido            0.2.1           py311haa95532_0
python-libarchive-c       2.9                pyhd3eb1b0_1
python-lmdb               1.4.1           py311hd77b12b_0
python-lsp-black          2.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-lsp-jsonrpc        1.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-lsp-server         1.10.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-lsp-server-base    1.10.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-slugify            5.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-snappy             0.6.1           py311hd77b12b_0
python-tzdata             2023.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-xxhash             2.0.2           py311h2bbff1b_1
python_abi                3.11                    4_cp311    conda-forge
pytoolconfig              1.2.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pytz                      2023.3.post1    py311haa95532_0
pyviz_comms               2.3.0           py311haa95532_0
pywin32                   306             py311h12c1d0e_2    conda-forge
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0           py311haa95532_1000
pywinpty                  2.0.10          py311h5da7b33_0
pyyaml                    6.0.1           py311ha68e1ae_1    conda-forge
pyzmq                     24.0.1          py311h7b3f143_1    conda-forge
qdarkstyle                3.2.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
qstylizer                 0.2.2           py311haa95532_0
qt-main                   5.15.2              h19c9488_10
qt-webengine              5.15.9               h5bd16bc_7
qtawesome                 1.2.2           py311haa95532_0
qtconsole                 5.5.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
qtconsole-base            5.5.1              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
qtpy                      2.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
re2                       2022.04.01           hd77b12b_0
referencing               0.33.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
reproc                    14.2.4               hd77b12b_1
reproc-cpp                14.2.4               hd77b12b_1
requests                  2.31.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
requests-file             1.5.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
requests-toolbelt         1.0.0           py311haa95532_0
responses                 0.13.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0
rfc3339-validator         0.1.4           py311haa95532_0
rfc3986-validator         0.1.1           py311haa95532_0
rich                      13.7.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
rope                      1.12.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
rpds-py                   0.18.0          py311hc37eb10_0    conda-forge
rtree                     1.0.1           py311h2eaa2aa_0
ruamel.yaml               0.17.21         py311h2bbff1b_0
ruamel_yaml               0.17.21         py311h2bbff1b_0
scikit-learn-intelex      2023.1.1        py311haa95532_0
scrapy                    2.8.0           py311haa95532_0
seaborn                   0.12.2          py311haa95532_0
service_identity          18.1.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
setuptools                69.1.0             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
sip                       6.7.12          py311h12c1d0e_0    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
smart_open                5.2.1           py311haa95532_0
sniffio                   1.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
snowballstemmer           2.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sortedcontainers          2.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinx                    5.0.2           py311haa95532_0
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    2.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
spyder                    5.5.1           py311h1ea47a8_0    conda-forge
spyder-kernels            2.5.0           win_pyh7428d3b_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.45.1               hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
stack_data                0.6.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
statsmodels               0.14.0          py311hd7041d2_0
tbb                       2021.8.0             h59b6b97_0
tbb4py                    2021.8.0        py311h59b6b97_0
tblib                     1.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
tenacity                  8.2.2           py311haa95532_0
terminado                 0.17.1          py311haa95532_0
text-unidecode            1.3                pyhd3eb1b0_0
textdistance              4.2.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
threadpoolctl             2.2.0              pyh0d69192_0
three-merge               0.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
tifffile                  2023.4.12       py311haa95532_0
tinycss2                  1.2.1           py311haa95532_0
tk                        8.6.13               h5226925_1    conda-forge
tldextract                3.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
toml                      0.10.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
tomli                     2.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tomlkit                   0.11.1          py311haa95532_0
toolz                     0.12.0          py311haa95532_0
tornado                   6.4             py311ha68e1ae_0    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.65.0          py311h746a85d_0
traitlets                 5.14.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
transformers              4.32.1          py311haa95532_0
twisted                   22.10.0         py311h2bbff1b_0
twisted-iocpsupport       1.0.2           py311h2bbff1b_0
typing-extensions         4.9.0                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         4.9.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2024a                h0c530f3_0    conda-forge
uc-micro-py               1.0.1           py311haa95532_0
ucrt                      10.0.22621.0         h57928b3_0    conda-forge
ujson                     5.4.0           py311hd77b12b_0
unidecode                 1.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
urllib3                   2.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
vc                        14.3                hcf57466_18    conda-forge
vc14_runtime              14.38.33130         h82b7239_18    conda-forge
vs2015_runtime            14.38.33130         hcb4865c_18    conda-forge
w3lib                     1.21.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
watchdog                  2.1.6           py311haa95532_0
wcwidth                   0.2.13             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1           py311haa95532_1
websocket-client          0.58.0          py311haa95532_4
werkzeug                  2.2.3           py311haa95532_0
whatthepatch              1.0.2           py311haa95532_0
wheel                     0.42.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
widgetsnbextension        4.0.5           py311haa95532_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0           py311haa95532_0
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
wrapt                     1.14.1          py311h2bbff1b_0
xarray                    2023.6.0        py311haa95532_0
xlsxwriter                3.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
xlwings                   0.29.1          py311haa95532_0
xxhash                    0.8.0                h2bbff1b_3
xyzservices               2022.9.0        py311haa95532_1
xz                        5.2.6                h8d14728_0    conda-forge
y-py                      0.5.9           py311hb6bf4ef_0
yaml                      0.2.5                he774522_0
yapf                      0.40.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ypy-websocket             0.8.2           py311haa95532_0
zeromq                    4.3.4                h0e60522_1    conda-forge
zfp                       1.0.0                hd77b12b_0
zipp                      3.17.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.13               hcfcfb64_5    conda-forge
zlib-ng                   2.0.7                h2bbff1b_0
zope                      1.0             py311haa95532_1
zope.interface            5.4.0           py311h2bbff1b_0
zstandard                 0.19.0          py311h2bbff1b_0
zstd                      1.5.5                hd43e919_0
```

Comment: Manually rejiggering DLLs is how horror stories in reproducibility begin. This looks appears you're messing around in **base**. If that's broken, then you'll need something like Micromamba to operate on the **base** and recover to a workable state using only Conda packages from `defaults` (`anaconda`) channels. Also, `anaconda` packages are mostly irrelevant - please show `conda` packages.